# Example of an hyperplane arrangement whose bounded region is not star-shaped

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Could anyone provide an example of an (essential) hyperplane arrangement whose bounded region is not star-shaped? (Appears as exercise 4.29 in "Oriented Matroids". Hint: six lines in the plane are enough).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the following example is suitable.

[image]